# TKinter: Can I style submenus to look like normal menus

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using `from tkinter.ttk import *` to override the old windows 98 style with the new windows 8 styled widgets. When I create a menu, it is styled as a new menu:

```
menu = Menu(master)
```

But when I add a submenu, it is styled as a old menu:

```
fileMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=False)
menu.add_cascade(label="Bestand", menu=fileMenu)
```

It looks like this:

[image]

What I would like is something like this:
[image]

Am I missing a import here, or is there a new ttk class for submenus? Please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The themeing enhancements to Tk (ttk) did not cover any changes to the menu items. These are being provided by the system on Windows so typically follow the windows standard look and feel. However, they use the older XP style menu look and feel and do not pick up the Vista/Win7 themed elements. The menubar itself is drawn by the Windows UI frame so has slightly different rules being applied.

As this is not implemented in Tk it is not available in Tkinter either. Sorry.